# Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign: error creating PKCS7 structure

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7

We are trying to sign the PAN no. with Digital Signature. We are taking the PAN No. in in.txt file but we are getting error -

**Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error creating PKCS7 structure!**

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath("in.txt"), "out.txt",
                'file://'.realpath('digitalsign.cer'),
               'file://'.realpath('private_key.pem'),
                array (), PKCS7_NOSIGS
            );
```

Kindly suggest what we can do to resolve this issue.

Comment: This also happened to me when I was trying to use the `cert.pem` when I should have been using the `fullchain.pem` file, which contains the full certificate chain required for certain PKCS operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your digital certificate and the Private key is an issue. Kindly create the Digital Certificate and Private Key with below command.

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout enc_key.pem -out selfcert.pem
```

Then after that use that certificate and private key and that will work for you. It worked for me and if still you face issue do comment.